# Tabulator data from Postgres Database

Tags: tabulator

I have tried to load the data from the file json.php with this code and it's work fine

```
$data = [
    [id=>1, name=>"Billy Bob", progress=>"12", gender=>"male", height=>1, col=>"red", dob=>"", driver=>1],
    [id=>2, name=>"Mary May", progress=>"1", gender=>"female", height=>2, col=>"blue", dob=>"14/05/1982", driver=>true],
    [id=>3, name=>"Christine Lobowski", progress=>"42", height=>0, col=>"green", dob=>"22/05/1982", driver=>"true"],
    [id=>4, name=>"Brendon Philips", progress=>"125", gender=>"male", height=>1, col=>"orange", dob=>"01/08/1980"],
    [id=>5, name=>"Margret Marmajuke", progress=>"16", gender=>"female", height=>5, col=>"yellow", dob=>"31/01/1999"],
];
```

//return JSON formatted data

```
echo(json_encode(["last_page"=>30, "data"=>$data]));
```

But my data is stored into a table of database in postgres.
in the same file I replaced the code with this one, but not work

```
$sql = "SELECT * from cross_reference";
$result = pg_exec($sql);
$data = array();
while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $data[] = $row;
}
echo (json_encode(["last_page"=>30, "data"=>$data]));
```

Can you help me please!?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on two things, the setup of your table and the data you are getting from your database.

If you have set up Tabulator for pagination then your response is correct, if you are not using pagination then you just need to return the json encoded ***data*** variable.

if you post a copy of your table definition object in your question i can give a more specific answer